# cant change title of program in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

this is my main module(this is for a point of sale system)

```
from tkinter import *
from SettingsMenuPOS import *
from Globalvariables import *



    root = Tk() #mainprogram
     
    root.iconbitmap('D:/Gatlabs logo.ico')
    
    
    
    opensettingsmenu = Button(root, text= "Open Settings", command = settingsmain)
    root.title(Mname)
    
    
    
    opensettingsmenu.grid(row= 0, column= 0)
    
        
    enter_button = Button( root , text = "ENTER", padx = 20, pady = 10, command= EnterEvent)
     
    enter_button.grid(row= 0, column= 1)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

im importing a setting module which changes the title of the program

```
from Globalvariables import *
from tkinter import *

#Mart Name
#user accounts




def settingsmain():

 settingmenu = Toplevel()
 settingmenu.iconbitmap('D:/Gatlabs logo.ico')

 global entryformartname

 labelformartname = Label(settingmenu, text = "Enter name of your store")
 entryformartname = Entry(settingmenu)
 entryformartname.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

 setmartname = Button(settingmenu, text = "setname", command = setname)
 setmartname.grid(row= 0, column = 1)

 settingmenu.mainloop()


def setname():

    global Mname, entryformartname
    Mname = entryformartname.get()
```

and im using a global variable Mname to display title of the program.
ive set the variable Mname = "Gatlabs" and the user can change it through entry.
but everytime i try to set the title it doesnt change :(
i hope to get better at coding but i suck. pls help im stuck

Comment: Did you get any error? What title do you get when you run your program? try to print `Mname` variable to see its content.

Comment: @ThunderPheonix no error, as i mentioned i set the mname to gatlabs to be changed by user. It stays gatlab and doesnt change

Comment: How the user could change the value of `Mname`? in input widget?

Comment: @ThunderPheonix yes when the user inputs in entry widget and presses setname it is supposed to change the title

Comment: @ThunderPheonix when setname button is clicked setname() is called and it picks text from entry widget

Comment: @ThunderPheonix when i print mname it gives the text from entry widget so thats fine

Comment: Check my answer bellow

Comment: @ThunderPheonix the thing is, if i do this then i will have to import the main module into settings module and it will create a cyclic dependency and give me an error

Comment: Updated. You have to get the window object from the button first, then change the title.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are thinking that using -:

```
root.title(var)
```

would make it so that anytime you change the var the title will change, but actually its that the title is changed only once and to the value of the var at the time it was supplied.

So if you want it to change everytime you change your var, then rather put it in the same function as the one where you change your var.

```
def update_title(title) :
     global var
     
     var = title
     root.title(title)
     return
```

and now every time you change the title run this down with the desired title as the argument.

I hope this solves your problem.
Also i hope you're safe in the time of an ongoing pandemic.

Answer (score 0):

Change `setname` function like this:

```
def setname():
    global Mname, entryformartname, setmartname 
    Mname = entryformartname.get()
    
    parent_name = setmartname.winfo_parent()
    parent = setmartname._nametowidget(parent_name)
    parent.title(Mname)
```

In your code, you just update `Mname` variable and window title stays unchanged.

### Update:

You can get the master from button widget which is the window itself. Then, change its title.